# Change Image in ListView if cursor has certain value

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have several markers on google maps and in each marker a ListView with several entries. Each entry can be liked by the user and if he has liked, there is stored an entry in the SQLite Database with the marker ID, the entry ID and if he has liked (1) or took the like back (0).
Now I want a filled heart to be shown below each List Item the user has liked. The problem is: Especially if there are many entries, there are randomly filled hearts, even if the user only liked one entry. Can someone figure out my mistake?

Activity, that saves in the SQLite Database if entry is saved:

```
getALlEntrysListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try {
                    JSONObject entryClicked = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
                    entryID = entryClicked.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                likeButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.heartImage);
                pos = "" + position;
                int objectID = Integer.parseInt(entryID);
                Cursor cursor = getLikes(dbh);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)) == 1) {
                            dbh.updateLike(dbh, markerID, objectID, Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), 0);
                            dislike(entryID);
                            cursor.close();
                        } else if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)) == 0) {
                            dbh.updateLike(dbh, markerID, objectID, Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), 1);
                            likeUpload(entryID);
                            cursor.close();
                        } else {
                            dbh.addLike(dbh, markerID, objectID, 1);
                            likeUpload(entryID);
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                } else {
                    dbh.addLike(dbh, markerID, objectID, 1);
                    likeUpload(entryID);
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Adapter, who sets the elements of the listView and changes the imgage to heart_filled if the entry is liked:

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ListCell cell;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pinboard_list_view_cell, null);
        cell = new ListCell();
        cell.likes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewLikes);
        cell.note = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewNote);
        cell.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewImg);
        cell.likeImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heartImage);
        convertView.setTag(cell);
    }
    else {
        cell = (ListCell)convertView.getTag();
    }
    cell.position = position;


    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = this.dataArray.getJSONObject(position);
        cell.likes.setText(jsonObject.getString("likes"));
        cell.note.setText(jsonObject.getString("note"));
        cell.entryID = jsonObject.getString("id");
        String img = jsonObject.getString("image");
        String urlForImageInServer = baseUrlForImage + img;

        Picasso.with(context)
            .load(urlForImageInServer)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
            .error(R.drawable.no_picture)
            .into(cell.img);



        objectID  = ""+cell.entryID;
        dbh = new DbHelper(context);
        cursor = getLikes(dbh);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)) == 1) {
                    cell.likeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_filled);
                }
                else if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)) == 0) {
                    cell.likeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                }
            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else {
            cursor.close();
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;

}

public static class ListCell {
    private TextView likes;
    private TextView note;
    private ImageView img;
    public ImageView likeImage;
    public int position;
    public String entryID;
}


public Cursor getLikes(DbHelper dbh) {
    dbase = dbh.getReadableDatabase();
    String columns[] = {dbh.LIKES_MARKERID, dbh.LIKES_ENTRYID, dbh.LIKES_LIKE};
    String selection = dbh.LIKES_MARKERID + " LIKE ? AND " + dbh.LIKES_ENTRYID + " LIKE ? ";
    String args[] = {markerID.toString(), objectID};
    Cursor cursor = dbase.query(dbh.TABLE_LIKES, columns, selection, args , null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Maybe I should add that the SQLite entries seem to be added correctly, because if I like an entry which heart was filled by mistake, it does not unfill it, but keeps it filled and increases the number of likes. Only then I can "dislike" it and then the heart is unfilled again.

Comment: Maybe it's because I haven't worked with sql and picasso too often, but in your ´do{if/else if}while(cursor.moveToNext());´, I can't see your cell changing, so it seems to change the same cell for every like in the database?

Answer (score 0):

First idea: If you only have 1 for like and 0 for dislike, change your query to if/else instead of if/else if; that's one possible error source fewer.

Second idea update: Something about what I posted as a comment under your post, but not experienced enough with these things to make a clear statement for now.

Comment: I tried your answer but it didn't change anything. Could it have to do something with scrolling through the List? Because as a example: I like the last list item, then I scroll up and the after next entry has a filled heart too. Then I restart the activity: all hearts are unfilled except the last entry so everything seems right but when I scroll up again suddently every second item has a filled heart...

Comment: Then it may indeed have something to do with the comment I put under your post.